# Angularjs highlight text

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have an AngularJS application that shows a list of highlighted text.

```
app.controller('textctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.showSelectedText = function() {
        $scope.selectedText =  $scope.getSelectionText();
    };

    $scope.text = [];

    $scope.getSelectionText = function() {
      var item = "";
      if (window.getSelection && window.getSelection().toString() != '') {
          item = window.getSelection().toString();
          $scope.text.push(item);

          console.log($scope.text)
      } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
          text = document.selection.createRange().text;
      }
      return $scope.text;
    };
});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="textctrl">
    <div class="form-group" style="width:60%;display: inline-table;height: 70%;" >
        <p style="padding: 3%; border:1px solid black" ng-mouseup="showSelectedText()">
            Literature, in its broadest sense, is any single body of written works. More restrictively, literature is writing that is considered to be an art form, or any single writing deemed to have artistic or intellectual value, often due to deploying language in ways that differ from ordinary usage.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="side-container" style="width:35%;display: inline-table;height: 70%;border:1px solid black;">
        <p>Hi</p>
    </div>
    <h2>
        Selected Text
    </h2>
    <!--<p ng-bind="selectedText"></p>-->
    <p ng-repeat="item in text track by $index">{$ $index $} - {$ item $}</p>
</div>
```

Whenever text is highlighted it is shown in the last `<p>` tag, I would like for that same text to be highlighted in the original text instance of `<p style="padding: 3%; border:1px solid black" ng-mouseup="showSelectedText()"> {$ body $} </p>` tags. I'm not sure what the best way to approach this is or the directives needed.

Comment: just apply your `style` to the `p` tag which you has been using `ng-repeat`

Comment: Yes but I want the first `<p>` tag to show the highlighted text. The second text simply prints out what the user has highlighted and highlighting that is not of use.

Comment: Still am not clear! Sorry! Are you want to highlight first `p` tag under the `ng-repeate` collection and rest of the `p` tags are no need highlighting ? Is am correct?

Comment: No problem, on the 4th line of the HTML code, I have text there. That text that I highlight from line 4 will be shown line 15th. However, I want the text that I highlight on line 4, to change style to background: yellow. Sorry if I didn't make too much sense.

Comment: You could check with this link https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle to setting dynamic style :)